# Python Annotations: Iterable Vs Hashable

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I don't think mypy can tell the difference between an `Iterable` and an `Hashable` because Iterables can be Hashable too.  Is there a way to differentiate the two of them?

```
@overload
def contains(o: Hashable) -> bool:...
@overload
def contains(o: Iterable[Hashable]) -> List[bool]:...
```

But mypy says overload 2 for "contains" would never be used because it's parameters overlap overload 1.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of `overload` `def`:

```
@overload
def contains(o: Iterable[Hashable]) -> List[bool]:...


@overload
def contains(o: Hashable) -> bool:...


def contains(o):
    pass


x = contains(2)
reveal_type(x)  # Mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
y = contains([3, 4])
reveal_type(y)  # Mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.bool]"
```